# wildcard SSL certificate on apache 2

Tags: apache, ssl

For some reason SSL is working fine on the main domain www.domainname.com / domainname.com
But it is not working on subdomains (im getting "This Connection is Untrusted")
Here are the steps i went through:

1. created a server certificate

   `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domainname.key -out domainname.csr`
2. typed *.domainname on the domain name
3. copied the certificate content to the SSL certificate supplier
4. downloaded the generated certificate
5. on httpd.conf

```
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    ServerName domainname.com

    ServerAlias *.domainname.com

    ServerAdmin admin@domainname.com

    ErrorLog "/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/https_error_log"

    TransferLog "/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/https_access_log"

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/domainname.com.crt"

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/domainname.key"

    SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/gd_bundle.crt"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">

        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin">

        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_request_log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you post the output of a 'openssl x509 -in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/domainname.com.crt -text' ? It seems that the final X.509 certificate is not a wildcard. Did you explicitely ask you supplier for a wildcard ? That's not the default, and you have to ask for a wildcard plan, not just supply a certificate request with *.domainname.com.

Comment: yes i did , bought the wildcard ssl. well posting the ssl here is a security risk isnt it ?

Comment: Nope, the X.509 SSL certificate is public, only the private key is, well, private :)

Comment: You can redact anything you want, but it would help to see the "Subject:" and "X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:"  sections, even if you replace your real domain name with domainname.com.

Comment: subject is CN = *.domainname.com
OU = Domain Control Validated
where can i find the C509v3 subject alternative ?

Comment: The "X509v3 Subject Alternative Name" is in the "X509v3 extensions" section, but you don't necesseraly have one. The thing is, if you have only this CN and no SAN, your subdomains should be working but not domainname.com (as domainname.com is not matched by *.domainname.com).

Comment: so how do you explain the domainname.com is working and the subdomains dont ?

Comment: I don't. Can you try to do an "openssl s_client -connect domainname.com:443 -showcerts" ? Is the DNS going to the correct IP ? Is the correct certificate sent by the server ?